# Adjacency Lists for graph representation using space O(number of edges)

Tags: java, graph, adjacency-list

i'm trying to represent a graph(connected-non directed-without weights) in java using adjacency lists (the space to represent the graph has to be O(m) where m is the number of edges) in order to find some informations usings BFS.  I get the information about the graph from a txt called graph.txt. I'm not sure if i use space O(m) to save the graph and also i'm not sure if this is a good way to save it in order to use BFS.

```
public class Vertex  {
    boolean visited = false;
    int number;
    ArrayList<Integer> adjList;
    public Vertex(int i) {
        this.number= i;
        adjList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    }
    public void addNeighbor(int i) {
        this.adjList.add(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can certainly make this representation work, you would require a way to access a `Vertex` by its `number` without searching the entire graph. In order for this to work you would need a list or an array `v[]` of `Vertex` objects, such that `v[i].number` is always equal to `i`.

Since you are going to need this array/list anyway, you might as well pre-populate it with "empty" `Vertex` objects, and change the representation to use a list of `Vertex` objects instead of `Integer`s, thus reducing the indirection:

```
public class Vertex {
    int number;
    List<Vertex> adjList = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    public Vertex(int i) {
        this.number= i;
    }
    public void addNeighbor(Vertex v) {
        adjList.add(v);
    }
}
```

Note that storing `visited` along with the `Vertex` is probably a bad idea, because `visited` is part of algorithm's state rather than part of graph's representation. You should keep an array of `visited` boolean variables separately from your representation, and only for the duration of your BFS run:

```
static void bfs(Vertex[] v, int start) {
    boolean[] visited = new boolean[graph.length];
    Queue<Vertex> q = new Deque<Vertex>();
    q.add(v[start]);
    while (q.peek() != null) {
        Vertex c = q.remove();
        if (visited[c.getNumber()]) {
            continue;
        }
        // Do something with the current vertex c
        ...
        // Mark c visited, and add its neighbors to the queue
        visited[c.getNumber()] = true;
        for (Vector a : c.neighbors()) {
            q.add(a);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your representation does use O(m) space. I have two different suggestions, given your representation.

1.
If you really want to represent the Vertex as a Class, then have it's list of adjacent verticies be a 
List<Vertex> instead of List<Integer>

or

2.
Since your Vertex class does not seem to hold any information other than the Integer value of the vertex, why not just use the Integer itself?
The graph could then be represented as

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> graph;
```

Where the graph[i] is the list of vertices connected to vertex i
This makes it so that you don't have to find matches from your integer id to Vertex instance.

Comment: It's not that i want to represent the Vertex as a Class, the first thing i did is to represent the graph as ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> graph; but wasn't sure if i can do BFS and other stuff like to print the vertices of each level with this representation.